# How to run a .m script in the same folder as the Simulink model using Model Callbacks?

Tags: matlab, simulink

Here is a model mdl/mdl.slx and its init script mdl/mdl_init.m. mdl/mdl_init.m should run as the model's preload callback. To make it foolproof, it's better that user do not need to add mdl/ to path to open the model. The user only needs to drag the model file to command window and all paths are added by mdl/mdl_init.m.

The problem is MATLAB do not recognize the current folder of the Simulink model. Using `mdl_init` or `run("./mdl_init.m")` in the preload callback doesn't work. `run("./mdl_init.m")` works if it's called by another .m script without adding path, so there may be some way to do that in Simulink.

On the other hand, since `run` accepts absolute path, getting the current Simulink model file/folder is enough to locate the script file. How to do that?

Comment: The files that are called in the callbacks must be added in the matlab search paths. You have to reference mdl_init.m somewhere before the model opens.